# C++: Design and cost for heavy multiple inheritance hierarchies

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class hierarchy with the following three classes:

```
template<int pdim >
class Function
{
   virtual double operator()( const Point<pdim>& x) const = 0;
};
```

Which is a function in pdim-dimensional space, returning doubles.

```
template<int pdim, int ldim >
class NodeFunction
{
   virtual double operator()( const Node<pdim,ldim>& pnode, const Point<ldim>& xLoc) const = 0;
};
```

Which is a function from the ldim-dimensional local space of a node in pdim-dimensional space.

```
template<int pdim, int ldim, int meshdim >
class PNodeFunction
{
   virtual double operator()( const PNode<pdim,ldim,meshdim>& pnode, const Point<ldim>& xLoc) const = 0;
};
```

*Reason 1* for this design: a NodeFunction is more general than a Function. It can always map the local ldim-point point to a pdim-point. E.g an edge (Node with ldim=1) maps the interval [0,1] into pdim-dimensional physical space. That is why *every Function is a NodeFunction*. The NodeFunction is more general as the NodeFunction is allowed to query the Node for attributes.

*Reason 2* for this design: a PNodeFunction is more general than a NodeFunction. Exactly one Node is accociated to every PNode (not vice versa). That is why *every PNodeFunction is a NodeFunction*. The PNodeFunction is more general as it also has all the context of the PNode which is part of a Mesh (thus it knows all its parents, neighbours, ...).

**Summary**: Every `Function<pdim>` is a `NodeFunction<pdim, ldim>` for any parameter of `ldim`. Every `NodeFunction<pdim, ldim>` is a `NodeFunction<pdim, ldim, meshdim>` for any parameter of `meshdim`.

**Question**: What is the best way to express this in C++, such that I can use `Function` in place of `NodeFunction` / `PNodeFunction`, such that the code is fast (it is a high performance computing code), such that the Code works for

The template parameters are not completely independent but rather dependend on each other:
- `pdim=1,2,3` (main interest) but it is nice if it works also for values of pdim up to 7.
- 'ldim=0,1,...,pdim'
- 'meshdim=ldim,ldim+1,...,pdim'

To consider the performance, note that obly a few functions are created in the program, but their operator() is called many times.

## Variants

I thought about a few ways to implement this (I currently implemented Variant 1). I wrote it down here so that you can tell me about the advanage and disadvantage of these approaches.

### Variant 1

Implement the above described inheritance `A<dim> inherits from B<dim,dim2>` via a helper template `Arec<dim,dim2>`. In pseudo Code this is

```
class A<dim> : public Arec<dim,dim>;
class Arec<dim,dim2> : public Arec<dim,dim2-1>, public B<dim,dim2>;
class Arec<dim,0> : public B<dim,dim2>;
```

This is applied both to inherit Function from NodeFunction and NodeFunction from PNodeFunction. As NodeFunction inherits roughly `O(pdim^2)` times from PNodeFunction how does this scale? Is this huge virtual table bad?

*Note*: In fact every Function should also inherit from `VerboseObject`, which allows me to print debugging information about the function to e.g. `std::cout`. I do this by virtually inheritung `PNodeFunction` from `VerboseObject`. How will this impact the performance? This should increase the time to construct a Function and to print the debug information, but not the time for `operator()`, right?

### Variant 2

Don't express the inheritance in C++, e.g. `A<dim>` doesn inherit from `B<dim,dim2>` bur rather there is a function to convert the two

```
class AHolder<dim,dim2> : public B<dim, dim> {

}

std::shared_pointer< AHolder<dim,dim2> > interpretAasB( std::shared_pointer< AHolder<dim> >)
 [...]
```

This has the disadvanate that I can no longer use `Function<dim>` in place of `NodeFunction<dim>` or `PNodeFunction<dim>`.

### Variant 3

What is your prefered way to implement this?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the description of your requirements, and I think you've probably actually left out some important parts before we can give you an answer. In particular, if a `Function` is-a `NodeFunction`, then does that mean that its `NodeFunction::operator()` will internally call ("forward to") `Function::operator()` in some way? The is-a relationship here isn't clear at all. Second, and this may answer your question for you: for standard (nonvirtual) inheritance, vtable size and inheritance depth should not affect performance: it's always one indirect call.

Comment: Finally, I did some HPC a few years back, and it happened to coincide with the time where I thought C++ templates were the best thing since sliced bread. So I have a sneaking suspicion you're overthinking this and may be better off implementing a solution to your actual problem, not building a framework for building said solution. I may of course be wrong, but I would suggest sticking to arrays/vectors of plain structs for most high-performance work.

Comment: @pmjordan: to your first comment. Indeed the Function provides NodeFunction::operator() via the call `operator()(node.map(xLoc))`. That means it holds that the relation between x and xLoc is `x = node.map(xLoc)`.

Comment: @pmjordan: so if every PNodeFunction additionally has a virtual inheritance from a class which I use purely for logging to console/file ( like http://trilinos.sandia.gov/packages/docs/r10.10/packages/teuchos/doc/html/classTeuchos_1_1Describable.html ) then this does not impact the performance except for the functions in those virtually inherited classes and the constructor, right?

Comment: Right, so for the forwarding, you'll pay a double virtual dispatch price, as you're essentially calling 2 virtual functions in sequence. Regarding the virtual base class: yeah, I'm *pretty* sure you'll only pay the extra price on the virtual functions declared in that base. If in doubt, look at the disassembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't comprehend you problem very well; that might be because I lack specific knowledge of the problem domain.
Anyway it seems like you want to generate a hierarchy of classes, with Function (most derived class) at the bottom, and PNodeFunction at the top (least derived class).
For that I can only recommend Alexandrescu's Modern C++ design book, especially the chapter on hierarchy generators.
There is an open source library stemming from the book called Loki.
[Here's the part that might interest you.](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=GP.HierarchyGenerators)

Going the generic meta-programming way might be the hardest but I think it will result in ease of use once setup, and possibly increased performance (that is always to be verified by the profiler) compared to virtual inheritance.

In any case I strongly recommend not inheriting from the Verbose object for logging, but rather having a separate singleton logging class.
That way you don't need the extra space in the class hierarchy to store a logging object.
You could have only the least derived class inherit from the Verbose object but your function classes are not logging objects; they use a logging object (I may be a bit pedantic here). 
The other problem is if you inherit multiple times from that base class, you'll end up with multiple copies of the logging object and have to use virtual inheritance to solve it.

Comment: do you mean this section "3.13. Class Generation with Typelists", our version of Alexandrescu's book doesn't have a chapter/section about hierarchy generators. If you mean this, then to my understanding that is already what I have used in Variant 1. But good to know, that it goes under this name.

Comment: Your comment about inheriting from Verbose object is intersting, but how do you implement that? I do want to have behaviour alike to virtual function. I.e. if I store an object as shared_ptr<Base> but it is in fact an instance of Derived, then when I print it to std::out then I want the information from the Derived class to be shown.

Comment: Yes I meant class generation with typelists; it is similar to your variant 1, except you are using multiple inheritance and he shows a way with single inheritance.
For the verbose object, in that case you can use a virtual function "ToString" or similar, passing as a parameter a logging object.
You then avoid paying the cost of a larger class.

Comment: Alexandrescu also uses multiple inheritance to solve this. The nice thing about his approach is, that the helper class that his helper class is so general that I could reuse his helper class and I wouldn't need to introduce a class like `class Arec`.

Comment: As for the VerboseObject. Ok, I have this virtual ToString method, if I then inherit classes multiple times, then I also have multiple times space allocated for the ToString method. As my VerboseObject is just a class with a single pure virtual "ToString" method, I think that this is equivalent.

Comment: There are two versions of his hierarchy generators, GenScatterHierarchy and GenLinearHierarchy. I was talking about GenLinearHierarchy, whereas I think you referred to GenScatterHierarchy. I think if your design is working and you haven't run into any issues; don't change it :)

Comment: As for the Verbose object you are right, in your case you do need polymorphism since you want each object to have a customized message output.